# List RTSP available streams

Tags: rtsp, ip-camera

I have an IP cam (Sricam SP009) and I'm able to access it via VLC using `rtsp`.
I was wondering if it would be possible to list all its available streams (as far as I know, they are `ovinf1` and `ovinf2`.
Now, is there a way I can discover if there are other streams? I've googled a lot and came up with nothing..
Thanks in advance

Comment: In the past I'd scan network (using Linux) for mac address'es. Find the manufacture associated with mac addy and go from there.